# UWP application not updating to screen orientation

Tags: c#, uwp

I have the following code which is not updating to screen orientation, I don't know how to fix it. I could not find any example on how to use DisplayInformation class. DisplayProperties class is now obsolete.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Name="native" />
        <TextBlock Name="current" />
        <TextBlock Name="autorotation" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```
DisplayInformation displayInformation;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape | DisplayOrientations.Portrait;
    displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
    displayInformation.OrientationChanged += DisplayInformation_OrientationChanged;
    UpdateContent();
}

private void DisplayInformation_OrientationChanged(DisplayInformation sender, object args)
{
    UpdateContent();
}

private void UpdateContent()
{
    native.Text = displayInformation.NativeOrientation.ToString();
    current.Text = displayInformation.CurrentOrientation.ToString();
    autorotation.Text = DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences.ToString();
}
```

Comment: By not responding to screen orientation you mean the `UpdateContent` method is not called when you rotate the screen? Haven't you locked screen rotation in Action Center? I have tested the code and the `CurrentOrientation` property is correctly updated when the screen orientation changes.

Comment: I am using a simulator in Visual Studio 2019. Yes Update Content method is not called when screen orientation is changed. I do not have any problem with the old DisplayProperties class.

Comment: Could you create a simple repro on GitHub so I can try the exact project you have problems with? Using the provided code I cannot reproduce it unfortunately...

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgdgTvs5s5ouhmak3zbDk-mnxN_N?e=sbj05B

Comment: Hi, I have tested your project and it indeed does work on my devices. The only thing that comes to my mind is if you have blocked some orientations of your app in Package.appxmanifest or locked rotation lock on your PC. Otherwise this should work properly. Can you possibly try on a different device?

Comment: I have tested on my local machine and it works fine. The problem seems to be with the simulator. Old DisplayProperties class works fine with it but with new DisplayInformation class it does not fire OrientationChanged event when simulator orientation is changed.